# Linq add non existing column to generated sql query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using LINQ in a dbContext within ASP MVC 5.

First, to put in context, the model

```
[Table("Datos_Garantizados")]
public partial class Datos_Garantizados
{
    [Key]
    public long Version { get; set; }

    public decimal? Perdidas_Vacio { get; set; }

    public decimal? Corriente_Vacio { get; set; }

    public decimal? Perdidas_Cortocircuito_P_S { get; set; }

    public decimal? Perdidas_Cortocircuito_P_T { get; set; }

    public decimal? Perdidas_Cortocircuito_S_T { get; set; }

    public decimal? Tension_Cortocircuito_P_S { get; set; }

    public decimal? Tension_Cortocircuito_P_T { get; set; }

    public decimal? Tension_Cortocircuito_S_T { get; set; }

    public decimal? Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_P_S { get; set; }

    public decimal? Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_P_T { get; set; }

    public decimal? Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_S_T { get; set; }

    public decimal? Bil_Primario { get; set; }

    public decimal? Bil_Secundario { get; set; }

    public decimal? Bil_Terciario { get; set; }

    public decimal? Aplicada_Primaria { get; set; }

    public decimal? Aplicada_Secundaria { get; set; }

    public decimal? Aplicada_Terciaria { get; set; }

    public decimal? SobreTemp_Aceite_Max { get; set; }

    public decimal? SobreTemp_Arroll_Medio { get; set; }

    public decimal? Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Primario_Secundario { get; set; }

    public decimal? Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Primario_Terciario { get; set; }

    public decimal? Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Secundario_Terciario { get; set; }

    public decimal? Potencia_Ref { get; set; }

}
```

The context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Perdidas_Vacio)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Corriente_Vacio)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Perdidas_Cortocircuito_P_S)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Perdidas_Cortocircuito_P_T)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Perdidas_Cortocircuito_S_T)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Tension_Cortocircuito_P_S)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Tension_Cortocircuito_P_T)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Tension_Cortocircuito_S_T)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_P_S)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_P_T)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Ref_Tens_Cortocircuito_S_T)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Bil_Primario)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Bil_Secundario)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Bil_Terciario)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Aplicada_Primaria)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Aplicada_Secundaria)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Aplicada_Terciaria)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.SobreTemp_Aceite_Max)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.SobreTemp_Arroll_Medio)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Primario_Secundario)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Primario_Terciario)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Ref_Perdidas_Cortocircuito_Secundario_Terciario)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Datos_Garantizados>()
        .Property(e => e.Potencia_Ref)
        .HasPrecision(18, 0);
}
```

When I try to get a list from the table Datos_Garantizados, the query adds an incorrect column to the query.

I tried this:

```
var Lista = db.Datos_Garantizados.ToList();
```

But when I try to compile it I get a SqlException:

> El of the column 'Transformador_Codigo_delfos' is not valid

In the SQL code generated by the query has the column `Transformador_Codigo_Delfos` is added which does not exist in the database.

Comment: Flagged to reopen, but fix the title also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the database design.

I has something like this.

```
Transformador  | Datos_Garantizados | Trafo_x_Garantizados
*codigo_delfos | *version           | *version
tipo           | resistencia        | codigo_delfos
// more fields | //more fields      |
```

The problem was a intermediate table, who make a 1-* relation.

I modified the database like

```
Transformador  | Datos_Garantizados | 
*codigo_delfos | *version           | 
 tipo          | codigo_delfos      | 
// more fields | more fields        |
```

And then correctly add the ForeignKey to Transformador Object inside Datos_Garantizados model.

```
[ForeignKey("Codigo_delfos")]
public virtual Transformador Transformador { get; set; }
```

Thanks!